# Unhandled ComException whith Shape

Tags: c#, excel, charts, shapes

I want to make a Group to Picture and Textbox and Straight Arrow Connector.

My code has an error `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC (ComException was unhandled)`.

```
ShapeRange shapeRange;
List<object> shapeArray = new List<object>();

Shape picture = worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(imageResultYearFiles[y], 
                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue,
                xAxis, yAxis, 135, 100);

Shape textBox = worksheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
                    xAxis + 48, yAxis - 30, 37, 21);

Shape c2 = worksheet.Shapes.AddConnector(
                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoConnectorType.msoConnectorStraight,
                tAxis2.leftX, tAxis1.rightY, (tAxis1.rightX - tAxis2.leftX) / 2,
                (tAxis1.rightX - tAxis1.rightY) / 2);

c2.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect(gene_textBox, 2);
c2.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect(shape2,4); 

shapeArray.Add(picture1.Name);   
shapeArray.Add(picture2.Name);
shapeArray.Add(textBox.Name);  
shapeArray.Add(c1.Name);
shapeArray.Add(c2 .Name);

if (shapeArray.Count > 1)
{
    shapeRange = worksheet.Shapes.get_Range(shapeArray.ToArray());
    shapeRange.Group();  // <-- Error
}
```

Why does the code have error `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC (ComException was unhandled)`?

Comment: please try : if (shapeArray.Count > 0)

Comment: It seems that the not affect. 
shapeArray.count = 7 ..

Comment: That's Excel Error 1004.  Google will give you a gazillion possible causes.  But it ultimately boils down to the same issue, Excel is not in the correct state to accept your call.  Usually because it is too busy trying to catch up.  Things like turning off autocalc and artificially slowing down your code with a Thread.Sleep() call tends to help.  Implementing IMessageFilter in an add-in is a more reliable fix.